# Accessing a store from another store - Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to create a store and inside access the data from another store to construct the proxy url.

Something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Post',{
extend:'Ext.data.Store', 
config: {
    model: 'MyApp.model.Post',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://mywebsite.com/get?userid=' + Ext.getStore('UserData').getAt(0).data.userid,
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
}
});
```

So, I'm basically trying to get the userid from another store to be able to construct the correct url. 
This doesn't work, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getStore'
```

What is the correct way to do this?

EDIT: Okay I put in a dummy URL and trying to change it with a listener, this is my store now:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Post',{   extend:'Ext.data.Store', 
config: {
      fields: [
                        'title', 'link', 'author', 'contentSnippet', 'content'
                    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
        }
    },
    listeners: [
        {
            beforeload: function(){
               console.log("store loaded");   //I DON'T SEE THIS IN CONSOLE
               return true;
            }    
        }
    ]
},

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you did nothing wrong, but the reason is sencha touch uses asynchronous loading and it seems that `Ext.getStore()` is not instantiated at the time your store is defined.

Let's try this method instead:

First, add a listener for `beforeload` event inside your store config:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Post',{
extend:'Ext.data.Store', 
config: {
    model: 'MyApp.model.Post',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        //url: you don't even need to set url config here, simply ignore it
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
},
listeners: [
    {
        fn: 'setUrl',
        event: 'beforeload'
    }
]
});
```

then declare a function like this, in the same file:

```
setUrl: function(){
    this.getProxy().setUrl(Ext.getStore('UserData').getAt(0).data.userid);
    return true;
}
```

This way, it's ensured to set the url for your store's proxy right before it's loaded. And basically at the time, all core methods are instantiated.

**Update: please try this with your Post store:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Post',{
   extend:'Ext.data.Store', 
   config: {
       //autoLoad: true,
          fields: ['title', 'link', 'author', 'contentSnippet', 'content'],
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'dummy url',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
            }
        },
   },

    initialize: function(){
        console.log("loaded!");
        this.getProxy().setUrl('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog');
        //return true;
    }    
});
```

**After reading the source code of the pull-to-refresh plugin, I see that Sencha Touch use an `Ext.data.Operation` instead of `Ext.data.Store.load()` function. So you will have to put it into the `initialize` method instead.**

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't quite work I'm now getting `Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Base#callParent] You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.` and the store does not load..

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I am not loading the store in my view.. I just have a list with `store: Post` what can I do about that? This is my list http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.plugin.PullRefresh

Comment: let's try adding this config to your store `autoLoad: true`. What do you get now?

Comment: what if you set autoLoad to false and manually call `Ext.getStore('Post').load()`?

Comment: nothing happens.. The view is not even loaded. I'm stuck on the three dots loading screen..

Comment: Yes. But I tried something else as well. I put in a dummy url so that it would load and then try to change it in the beforeload event but the event never fires. Please have a look at the question, I added that in.

Comment: seems I need get my hands dirty into this. Please update a fiddle and I'll help you out https://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: Wow thanks! Here you go: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/27c
You need to pull the view down and release for the store to load..

Comment: hi MinaHany I cannot see your UserData store, did you upload it yet?

Comment: Oh just forget that.. If I could get the beforeload to work then I'm good.

Comment: Ohhh, I had a feeling the plugin was doing something out of the convention. Thanks a lot man! All is working fine now!

Comment: @ MinaHany: yes it uses `Ext.data.Operation` and apply it as a parameter to `read` action of the store's `proxy`. That's why there's nothing to do with `load` and `beforeload`. There are 2 ways: overriding `getProxy()`, or overriding `initialize`. The 2nd solution is clearly easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('UserData')` to get the store instance.

But in your case, I would use this somewhere, where you work with the userid:

```
var postsStoreInstance = ...;
postsStoreInstancegetProxy()._extraParams.userid = userid;
```

It adds a query paremetry to the store's proxy url

Comment: this has no difference since `Ext.getStore()` is the short-hand way

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it is the correct way. What is the code of your store definition?

Make sure your store has `storeId: 'UserData'`.

See this working example:

```
Ext.define('User', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields: [
       {name: 'id'}
   ]
});

Ext.create( 'Ext.data.Store', {
   model: 'User',
   storeId: 'UserData'
});

Ext.define('MyApp.store.Post',{
   extend:'Ext.data.Store', 
   config: {
       model: 'MyApp.model.Post',
       proxy: {
           type: 'ajax',
           url: 'http://mywebsite.com/get?userid=' + Ext.getStore('UserData'),
           reader: {
               type: 'json'
           }
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: please note that the error is `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getStore' `

Comment: Could you then post your store definition of store `'UserData'`?